# cant grab text of div after ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to save text to a div with this code:

```
var request = $.get("http://localhost:36262/wordlist/list.txt");
request.success(function (result) {
    $('.dic').text(result);
});
```

after I try to grab the text of that div and am unable.  I see the text displayed on screen.

```
var words = $('.dic').text();
```

when I debug I see the variable is empty but on the screen the text has been added.

Comment: you probably didn't wait long enough. Ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: move your `var words...` line to inside the `.success(` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
request.success(function (result) {
  words = result  
  $('.dic').text(words);
});
```

And work with the now set global variable in a later function. As Kevin B has commented, ajax is asynchronous as your .dic -> text might be empty at the time you try to access it.

Better way would be, depending on your use scenario, to set

```
var words
```

and call the next function with the var as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Since ajax is Asynchronous you can't get result outside immediately, so you need to call a callback as an solution

```
var request = $.get("");
request.success(function (result,yourfunction) {
    $('.dic').text(result);
    youfunction(result);
});
```

then do whatever you cant to do with "words"

```
 function yourfunction(words){
 //use words here
  }
```